# Why can't `atomic` and `synchronized` attributes be applied to the same method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

In Java, threading is one of the fundamental topics within the language. The two commonly used attributes associated with this topic is `atomic` and `synchronized`, which are used for different purposes. As I understand it, `atomic` methods must execute in its entirety, whereas `synchronized` methods place a "lock" on the objects used with the method, preventing other threads from causing memory errors or interference. My question is why can't the `atomic` and `synchronized` attributes be used in the same method declaration.

Comment: There's no such thing as an `atomic` attribute. Atomicity is a concept.

Comment: @shmosel https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: What's your point?

Comment: There is nothing in that link about an '`atomic` attribute', or indeed about any attribute at all. You are making it up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronization while using AtomicInteger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253260/synchronization-while-using-atomicinteger)

Comment: @Mikenno I see no evidence of that, and I see no point in guessing about it. He has clearly stated a (mistaken) belief in the existence of an '`atomic` *attribute*', on '*methods*', and I am here quoting his words. It's up to the OP to clarify his question if he thinks it has been misunderstood.

Comment: @EJP right, i suppose, still new at this apreciate the advice and pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked article is describing a category of different actions that result in all-or-nothing changes. There is no atomic keyword and no concept of designating a method as atomic.

It wouldn't make sense to worry about whether something on a synchronized block was executed atomically because the synchronization should be providing sufficient guarantees of excluding other threads and making changes visible across threads; if no other threads can access an object while it's changing it does not matter if the change is atomic.

You could combine atomic variables with synchronized methods or blocks. Say you want to expose a counter that is incremented within a synchronized method so other threads can get its current value without acquiring the lock. Using an AtomicInteger for the counter would update its value and make it visible even while the current thread is still executing the synchronized method.