# Does AtomicInteger handle synchronization?

Tags: java, atomic, atomicinteger

If two threads both increment same `int i` using **i++**, we could get a problem, as **i++** is not atomic operation. That is why there is `AtomicInteger.increment()`, which makes incrementing atomic. So if we had 1 core and 2 threads doing `.increment()`, there could be absolutely no problem (as it can't be suspended in the middle of operation).

But what if we had 2 cores and 2 threads and they parallelly (at exactly the same time) call that `increment()`?

Could there be possibility that they load same value of `int i`? Meaning if `int i` was **1**, end result would be **2** and not **3**. In that case we don't care if it is atomic operation as they both took same value at the same time..

Bottom line: is synchronization handled by AtomicInteger?

Comment: Maybe this helps?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253260/synchronization-while-using-atomicinteger

Comment: Especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17254001/1531124

Comment: Pff thanks, after reading this I would never use it as is not thread safe. I can't think of example where I would use it instead of synchronized block now..

Comment: I also suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519664/difference-between-volatile-and-synchronized-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could there be possibility that they load same value of `int i`?

Yes, there is, but it's handled for you.

The `incrementAndGet` method uses an atomic "compare and set" operation that sets the incremented value *but only if a new value was not already set*. If the compare fails, `incrementAndGet` fetches the new value and tries again.

The net effect is, it is safe to use `incrementAndGet` from multiple threads.